# jQuery - Context menu on 'option' element in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, contextmenu

Not sure if this is just me, but I can't seem to get the context menu to work on an option element child of a select element within IE.  This does work OK if Firefox, however.

Any tips on how to get around this issue?

Here is the relevant code inside $(document).ready():

```
$(".search-results option").bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The .search-results class is attached to an HTML `select` element which has multiple option `children`.

Edit:
Just to clarify, my breakpoint on `e.preventDefault();` never gets hit in IE, but it does in Firefox.  So I think the event might not even exist in IE?

Comment: The event [does exist in IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/contextmenu.html), but `<option>` elements are notoriously finicky with event bindings, typically requiring that the binding be on the `<select>` instead.

Comment: Any examples I can look at?  I did have no problem with the binding on the `<select>`, but I wasn't quite sure how to get the appropriate `<option>` from that point.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe it has to be on instead of bind, like so

```
$(".search-results option").on("contextmenu", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

you can view the details on this link https://api.jquery.com/contextmenu/

hope this helps. :)